# Can a AIML chatbot support unlimited queries from user?

Tags: chatbot, aiml

I wanted to make a chatbot to answer questions from user with AIML but i was wondering if there is any limitation because i think i will need that the chatbot supports unlimited queries because we don't know how big this project will be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Humans have a limit to the number of clients they can handle at once. However, with chatbots, there is no such constraint and they can handle as many queries as required at once.

You can use [this](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/ai/chatbot-40404) kind of asset from the unity asset store to implement and customise the chatbot quickly.

Do not worry about query limits. That can be easily scaled up.

You can use the free A.L.I.C.E. AIML as well. It includes a knowledge base of approximately 41,000 categories. Here’s an example of one of them:

```
<category>
<pattern>WHAT ARE YOU</pattern>
<template>
<think><set name=”topic”>Me</set></think>
I am the latest result in artificial intelligence,
which can reproduce the capabilities of the human brain
with greater speed and accuracy.
</template>
</category>
```

Comment: Nice!!Thank you again Divyansh

Comment: I sent you an email in that about.me page

Answer (score 0):

I run Mitsuku, which is a very popular AIML chatbot. The website version alone deals with over a million interactions every month with no issues at all. It has over 350,000 categories and can deal with thousands of concurrent users at the same time.
It's hosted at [www.pandorabots.com](http://www.pandorabots.com)

Comment: Sorry, I don't use Unity and can't answer. However, I used AIML with Flash and it handled many users with no issues at all.